# How to optimise laggy JetPack Compose layout

Tags: android, performance, android-jetpack-compose, lag

I'm using a `HorizontalPager` from accompanist package. The pager will have 1 page for each exercise stored by the user.

Each page in the pager has a `LazyColumn` which contain multiple cards with controls such as `IconButton`s and `BasicTextField`. The number of cards depends on number of sets configured by the user. I expect the typical number to be between 1 to 8 but only 3 to 5 would be visible on the screen at any given time (depending on the screen size and resolution).

The issue is that when this layout produces noticeable lag (animations skip frames) every time the `HorizontalPager` needs to build a new page that has more than 3 cards. This happens when swapping between pages. The same happens in debug and release versions running on a real device (Galaxy S10e) and emulator.

I'm trying to optimise this layout, so each frame renders in no more than 16ms regardless of the number of cards shown on the screen.

I've previously tried to solve this issue by setting fixed heights to some composables but that didn't help much. I've also tried using `Text` instead of `BasicTextField`, which would be then replaced with `BasicTextField` when users taps on the text but this hasn't helped much, therefore I removed this implementation.

Do you have some suggestions how performance of this layout could be improved to eliminate the lag?

Below is my code, screen shoot of the app screen and profiler:

```
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun WorkoutSessionScreen(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

    Scaffold(
        topBar = { MyTopAppBar(navHostController = navHostController) }
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
                .imePadding()
        ) {
            HorizontalPager(
                count = 10, state =
                pagerState,
                itemSpacing = 16.dp
            ) {
                Log.e("==>", "Building horizontal pager")
                TrackingControls()
            }

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(70.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color(0xFAF7F7FF))
                    .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
            ) {
                Column(
                    Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Divider(color = Color(0x2A5C5C5C))
                    BottomControls()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun TrackingControls() {

    LazyColumn(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 8.dp)
    ) {
        items(6) { item ->
            SetsAndRepsTrackingControls(
                modifier = Modifier
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun BottomControls() {
    Text(text = "Bottom Controlls")
}
```

```
@Composable
fun SetsAndRepsTrackingControls(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val add = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_round_add_24)
    val remove = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_round_remove_24)


    Card(
        modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
            .padding(vertical = 16.dp, horizontal = 8.dp),
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
    ) {
        Column() {
            ControlsHeader()
            TrackingInput(label = "REPS", add, remove)
            Divider(color = Color.LightGray)
            TrackingInput(label = "WEIGHT (KG)", add, remove)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ControlsHeader() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(56.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary, RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Text(text = "Set 1")
        Text(text = "CheckBox")
    }
}

@Composable
private fun TrackingInput(label: String = "Preview", add: Painter, remove: Painter) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(60.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        IconButton(onClick = {}) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_round_remove_24),
                contentDescription = "Minus",
                tint = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
            )
        }

        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            BasicTextField(
                singleLine = true,
                value = "8",
                onValueChange = {},
                textStyle = TextStyle(
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
                ),
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
            Text(
                text = label,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.overline.copy(color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface)
            )
        }

        IconButton(onClick = { Log.d("==>", "tada") }) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_round_add_24),
                contentDescription = "Minus",
                tint = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Application Printscreen]

**This profiler print screen shows rendering of a single card called SetsAndRepsTrackingControls**

[image: Profiler]

Comment: The problem is not with the content ... but actually the problem is with the HorizontalPager of accompanist library ...

Comment: And by the way I am seeing the layout in vertical order ... why are you using HorizontalPager ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AgentP. Each Horizontal Page has a LazyColumn, which is why you're seeing vertical items on the page. You're right, it seems to be an issue with HorizontalPager or LazyColumn. I decided to implement this page using Fragments and XML and it works just fine now.

Comment: I have the same error... A lot of lag using HorizontalPager inside LazyColum

Comment: You should use androidx.compose.foundation.pager.HorizontalPager insdead of com.google.accompanist.pager.HorizontalPager because since API 0.30.0 HorizontalPager is deprecated in Accompanist library. It have helped me in my case

Comment: There is an interesting answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/76750031/10250334](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76750031/10250334)