# Jetpack Compose Horizontal Pager Swipe Delay

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a Jetpack Compose App that uses a Horizontal Pager. The behavior I am seeing is that when I swipe to my next page it moves smooth, but when I swipe back the screen advances about 3/4 of the way and pauses and then if I wait it completes the swipe.

Question:

Is this normal and controlled by the Fling Behavior?

Or could it be my implementation?

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: We use a Horizontal Pager and I have not experienced this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the content in horizontal pager.When I use a simple coil image, it works fine.But when I have vertical pager/lazy column inside a horizontal pager, it lags.
Also mentioned here:
[How to optimise laggy JetPack Compose layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69934407/how-to-optimise-laggy-jetpack-compose-layout)

Comment: Yes, agreed. I have vertical and horizontal pager and it is laggy.

Comment: Exactly.It may be due to offScreenPageLimit property that was removed in 0.19 version of Accompanist library.Now you don’t have control over it & by default I guess it is at 2. 
What I did to fix this was to move back to 0.18 version of Accompanist & it’s working fine without lag

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the tip, I may try that out.  Another postI saw, they implemented the pager portion of their app using the native Android controls and not Jetpack Compose for that screen in their app.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick to solve this issue:

You have to use the **beyondBoundsPageCount** parameter set to 1 to load the two adjacent page contents, and **observe settled page** to start loading upcoming content only when you stop scrolling (which means: the current page is settled).

The default pager behavior is to start loading the content of adjacent pages at the beginning of scroll -even by 1px- and that makes your scroll janky because of entering composition that blocks main thread.

I’ve put more explanation on this [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/292136289)

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = initialPage()) { items.size }
val beyondBoundsPageCount = 1
HorizontalPager(
    modifier = modifier,
    state = pagerState,
    beyondBoundsPageCount = beyondBoundsPageCount,
    key = { items[it].id },
) { page ->
    @Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")
    val page by rememberUpdatedState(newValue = page)
    val authorizedPage = {
        abs(pagerState.settledPage - page) <= beyondBoundsPageCount
    }
    val authorizedTiming by produceState(initialValue = false) {
        while (pagerState.isScrollInProgress) delay(50)
        if (abs(pagerState.settledPage - page) > 0) {
            delay(1000)
            while (pagerState.isScrollInProgress) delay(50)
        }
        value = true
    }
    // Conditions to show content
    val showContent by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            authorizedPage() && authorizedTiming
        }
    }

    if (showContent) {
        // Content
    } else {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
    }
}
```